# Call controller on afterCreate

Tags: sails.js

I have the following code for my `Sessions` model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

  },
  afterCreate: function(value,next) {
    next();
  }

};
```

And the following `Sessions` Controller:

```
module.exports = {

  saveSession: function(res,req) {
    console.log('in save');
  }
};
```

I want to save a value to a user's session `afterCreate`

How can I call the `saveSession` function from my model? I tried `Sessions.saveSession()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a session model and it's not a good idea to call a controller method directly.

I'd recommend just set `req.session` when you're trying to save the session and it'll be auto-saved when you respond from that controller action.

`afterCreate` will never have access to `req` unless you pass it down which I wouldn't recommend.

The pattern is something like:

```
{
  // …
  login: function (req,res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.param('username'),
    password: req.param('password')
  }).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    if (!user) return res.view('/login');
    req.session.user = user.toJSON();
    return res.redirect('/dashboard');
  });
}
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to **save a value to a cookie** or **create another database record** am i correct?

If so, you dont need to call a controller action from the model (not recommended), you just need to create a new record or save the value to the cookie, here are some alternatives that i see possible in your scenario.

**creating another record:**

```
    // on models/YourModel
    module.exports = {

      attributes: {

      },
      afterCreate: function(newlyInsertedRecord,next) {
          ModelOrResource.create({
              param1: newlyInsertedRecord.attributeYouWant,
              param2: value2
              // and so on
          }).exec(function(err, recordCreated){
              if(err) return next(err);
              // do somethign with recordCreated if you need to
              // ...
              next();
          })

      }

    };
```

**Saving a value to a cookie:**

```
    module.exports = {

        attributes: {

        },
        afterCreate: function(newlyInsertedRecord, next) {
            // do some other stuff not related to calling a controller action ;)
            next();
        }

    };
```

This code was retrived from snippets from my own projects, so it should work on sails 0.9.x

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can't access `req` from the models.

Comment: Thanks Kai, this was a prototype code i was writting when i was messing arround with sails 0.8 or something, not sure why i put it there.